# fread a single int from bin file gives me a segmentation fault in C

Tags: c, fread

I  want your help in something that should be easy and I do not know why it does not work. I want to read the first data from a bin which I know that it is an int. I am using the following part of code, but I am getting a segmentation fault:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
    {
        int *data;
        /*opening file*/
        FILE *ptr_myfile;
        ptr_myfile=fopen(myfile.bin","rb");
        if (!ptr_myfile)
        {
            printf("Unable to open file!\n");
            return 1;
        }
        /*input file opened*/
        printf("I will read the first 32-bit number\n");
        /*will read the first 32 bit number*/
        fread(&data,sizeof(int),1, ptr_myfile);
        printf("Data read is: %d\n",*data);     

        fclose(ptr_myfile);
        return 0;
    }
```

I also tried calling it like this:

```
fread(data,sizeof(int),1, ptr_myfile);
```

It should be something with the pointer but I cannot see what.

Comment: `int *data;` --> `int data;`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Change:

- `int *data;` to `int data;`
- `printf("Data read is: %d\n",*data);` to `printf("Data read is: %d\n",data);`

You are reading the `int` into a pointer, then trying to dereference the pointer (which is has a value that's meaningless as a pointer).

Answer (score 3):

You don't have any memory allocated to `data` and in the first example code you are not using the pointer correctly. This is an alternative that could work:

```
int data;
```

and then you would use it like so:

```
fread(&data,sizeof(int),1, ptr_myfile);
```

In your original code, here you are writing an `int` into a pointer:

```
fread(&data,sizeof(int),1, ptr_myfile) ;
```

and then this `*data` will be dereferencing an invalid pointer. In the alternative case:

```
fread(data,sizeof(int),1, ptr_myfile);
```

you will be using a pointer that has no memory allocated to it.

Comment: You have two same lines 2-3 in your code `fread(&data,sizeof(int),1, ptr_myfile);`. Is this meant to be so?

Answer (score 2):

You are passing address of a non-allocated pointer. Remove `*` from `data`:

```
int data;
...
fread(&data, sizeof(int), 1, ptr_myfile);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are overthinking the question of pointers. The function `fread()` needs to know the address at which to store the data it reads, so it is passed a pointer. That does not mean that the buffer used by `fread` should be a pointer, just that `fread` needs a pointer to that buffer.

So your first error is writing `int *data;` where you really just mean `int data;`. You say the data element to be read is an `int`, so you would just declare an `int` to hold it.

You correctly called `fread` to read the data by passing a pointer to actual allocated and valid memory (i.e. `&data`), avoiding a different beginner pitfall of passing the uninitialized pointer to integer you declared earlier.

Your actual error is caused by writing `*data` in the call to `printf`. The `*` operator takes a pointer and *dereferences* it. In other words, it assumes that the pointer points to something, and retrieves that value. However, when the pointer being dereferenced does not point to any valid *something*, you have a problem.

And here is where you were lucky. The value you read from the file was then treated by the `*` operator as an address in memory, but happened to be an address that was not part of the memory accessible to your process, which caused the system to take notice and halt the process with a segmentation fault. As a result, you learned immediately that there was an error in your code.

If you were not lucky, the integer you read from the file when treated as an address of memory could have been the address of something already present in your process. You would not have caused a segmentation fault, and you would by puzzled by why `printf` produced a strange answer.

Now imagine if you read a value from an untrusted source and treated it as an arbitrary address. An attacker could use that error to learn something about your program. Worse, if you had written to the memory referenced by that pointer, the attacker could conceivably change the behavior of your program.

As a final point, note that reading and writing `int` (or any other data type) is safe and acceptable as long as that file will never be transferred to a different system. Not all systems agree on even the simplest definitions like the number of bytes occupied by an int (which you did handle correctly by using `sizeof(int)`, but not in a way that would allow exchanging the file with a system with a different integer size), or even the order of those bytes in memory. Correctly addressing these issues is a large subject.